# Infer generic type from implementing class

Tags: java, generics

Assume I have an abstract class `Pipeline<T>` which contains some elements of Type `T` and an implementing class `IntPipeline` which extends `Pipeline<Integer>`.

```
abstract class Pipeline<T> {
  abstract T getNextItem();
}
```

```
class IntPipeline extends Pipeline<Integer> {
  Integer getNextItem() {
    // generate integer here
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Now I want to write some tests. Since all implementations of `Pipeline` will have similar tests, I want to create an abstract base class to define some standard tests:

```
abstract class PipelineTest<S, T extends Pipeline<S>> {

  private final Class<T> clazz;

  protected PipelineTest(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  abstract T createInstance();

  @Test
  void canBeSerializedAndDeserialzed() {
    var serializer = ...;
    T pipeline = createInstance();
    var json = serializer.toJson(pipeline);
    T deserializedPipeline = serializer.fromJson(json, clazz);
    assertEquals(pipeline, deserializedPipeline);
  }
}
```

So the concrete test would look like this:

```
class IntPipelineTest extends PipelineTest<Integer, IntPipeline> { // redundant information here

  IntPipelineTest() {
    super(IntPipeline.class);
  }

  IntPipeline createInstance() {
    return new IntPipeline();
  }
}
```

As you can see, when I create a concrete test, I need to pass redundant information there. I'm telling the compiler, that I will create a test for a pipeline of type `Integer`. From my understanding this could be infered from `IntPipeline`. Therefore I'm suspecting that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with generics.

So is there any way to restructure the code so that I can create a test without the need to declare the `Integer` type explicity?

Comment: When the abstract class only has abstract methods, then there is no point in testing the abstract class and instead of using a test implementation just use one of your existing sub-classes as a proxy.

Comment: I am not trying to test the abstract class. I am basically creating a number of tests (like `canBeSerializedAndDeserialzed`) which should be excuted for *every* implementation of the abstract class. So the idea is, that whenever someone creates a new `Pipeline`, they can just derive their test from `PipelineTest` and a number of tests is executed automatically.